# MVC3 required fields in datamodel results in DIV

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I want my view that has fields on it to

1) make sure all required fields are met.

2) do an ajax call and post the results back to a DIV Tag on the same page

I have tried a couple of things

- Ajax.Beginform with an updateTargetId of the div.

However I have an existing action which on post checks some fields posted and does a RedirectToAction to another action if these fields are met.
This is causing me grief utlimately since it's going to a different view.

- using jQuery and $('form').submit, checking valid() and doing a post.. and that worked... (results went into DIV on the same page) but then the required fields didn't get checked.  It kept thinking valid() was true.

Can someone give me a good way to get this accomplished?

Comment: if you remove the ajax call (2nd approach) the validations get triggered? are you pre-populating the fields?

Comment: when I had the jquery ajax call with a valid() .. it didn't seem to trigger the required fields I defined in the jquery code.  I am setting the 3 dropdownlists I have to a value of "Select an item" but there is an Amount field I am not and it didn't stop it when I didn't enter something there.  The Required DataAnnotation on the model I tried did however...   but when I put the jquery back in with that in place.. it overrides it I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first question

**1)  make sure all required fields are met.**

[Use Annotations for Data Validation](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=769)

and for,

**2) do an ajax call and post the results back to a DIV Tag on the same page**

**Ajax Call**

```
var url = '@Url.Action("GetData")';
$.ajax({
url: url,
type: 'GET',
cache: false,
data: { value: strId},

success: function (result) {
$('#result).html(result);
}
});
```

**Action**

```
public ActionResult GetData(string id)
{
return Json(new {foo="bar", ball="dragon"});
}
```

[Full Article](http://yassershaikh.com/how-to-call-an-action-from-javascript-or-jquery-in-mvc-3-razor/)

Comment: ok so if I want to do this ajax call on the forms submit.. how does that work.  When I try this with $('form').submit ( ) it seems to override the one defined with the data annotations.

Comment: I still can't get it to do anything but show the new view instead of it going into the div.  I know I must be doing something wrong but I can't see it.  IF you can help without seeing the code, or suggest something, please do.  I will put the code up later on however.

Comment: dataAnnotations was working.. ajax call no. It kept showing the error on the screen for the missing field but kept allowing the form action to continue, even with preventdefault, return false, didn't matter.      I finally dropped back and punted... Changed the input type to button. Made my own validate fcn and ajax call. Then it worked. No Data Annotations involved.